# I want to make an array of checkbox in scrollviewer control using WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, scrollviewer

I have a list of strings and I want to convert it to checkboxes control in scrollviewer control. How can I do this? Any ideas? The list consists of courses and I want to make it as checkboxes so student can choose some of them.

Comment: Show us what you have in list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**XAML** Part :

```
   <ScrollViewer>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding .}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox Content="{Binding Path=.}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

**Code-behind** part :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new string[] {"course1", "course2"};
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would a listbox control with Checkbox as its items work for you?

This is part of a WPF Xaml code that I wrote for a checkbox list:

```
        <ListBox Name="CheckBoxDataListBox">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Width="Auto" Height="20" Margin="0">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                            <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" Padding="0" DataContext="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}"></CheckBox>
                        </Grid>
                        <Label Name="SelectLabel" Grid.Column="1"  Padding="0" DataContext="{Binding}" Content="{Binding Value}"></Label>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Comment: when I add items in it it just add labels not checkbox can you text it again or discuss how it work ?

Comment: Did you make sure you got the grid columns correct? the Label may have been placed over the checkbox control? Make sure their is enough column width. Comment out the label and see if the checkbox is displayed.

Comment: I copied the code from my project where the text needs to be displayed on the other side of the checkbox. I couldn't do it with the checkbox available (or couldn't find out how).

Comment: @Vivek - in that case you just need to set  `FlowDirection="RightToLeft"`

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the collection of strings as the `ItemsSource` of a `ListBox` and set `ListBox.ItemTemplate` to a `DataTemplate` that includes a checkbox.

For example, see [WPF ListBoxItem selection problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127556/wpf-listboxitem-selection-problem).