# WPF, ListBox's ItemTemplate has CheckBox, but CheckBox does not seem to be the item

Tags: wpf, listbox, keyboard, focus, checkedlistbox

I just wanted the CheckListBox I used to use with Windows Forms.

```
    <ListBox>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox  Content="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

At first this seemed to work, but there was numerous problems. In short, it just works like a CheckBox is floating on the real item, rather than the CheckBox is the item.

I mean, (1)clicking the checkbox's text would not select the ListBox item, (2)pressing up and down key does not focus the checkbox. I have to click the checkbox in order to focus it. I have searched Google for solutions but there weren't clean solutions. Am I wanting too much?

I just want the behavour of CheckedListBox...

I worked around (1) by handling the PreviewMouseDown event of the checkbox and manually selecting the item. It does not seem to be clean.

Answer (score 9):

This is, because your `CheckBox` is in a `ListBox`. It is handled as an item of the list with all it's features.

If you want to build only a list of checkboxes and don't need selection-logic of the list, use an [ItemsControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx) instead of the `ListBox`. The usage is equal. If you want to have your CheckboxList scrollable,  use ScrollViewer to wrap the ItemsControl.

```
<ScrollViewer>
   <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding YourItemsCollection">
      <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>    
          <DataTemplate>                
             <CheckBox  Content="{Binding Name}"/>
          </DataTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
   </ItemsControls>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Selected answer for the linked question ([WPF ListBoxItem selection problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127556/)) provides a clean solution!  Was stuck with the same scenario -> found your question -> found the other one with the remedy.  HTH!